# Why is exports not displayed as an object in terminal while using Export Literals in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, module.exports

If exports is an object in node module object, why it isn't shown as an object in the terminal (Command Prompt in windows 10)?

Here is the code in Name.js module :

```
    module.exports ="Hello World"; 
    console.log(module);
```

and what I see in ternianl is this :

```
Module {
  id: '.',
  path: 'D:\\Projects\\Node\\Tutorial',
  exports: 'Hello World',
  parent: null,
  filename: 'D:\\Projects\\Node\\Tutorial\\names.js',
  loaded: false,
  children: [],
  paths: [
    'D:\\Projects\\Node\\Tutorial\\node_modules',
    'D:\\Projects\\Node\\node_modules',
    'D:\\Projects\\node_modules',
    'D:\\node_modules'
  ]
}
```

As you see exports `exports: 'Hello World'` isn't an object and is a string.

Comment: You're literally setting it to a string. Set it to an object, and it'll be an object.

Comment: Yes, I did it, but can an object be a string as well?

Comment: You replaced the `module.exports` object with a string.  Perhaps you meant to do something like `module.exports.greeting = "Hello World";` where you leave the object in place and add a property to it.

Comment: This is all just plain Javascript so `exports` is just a property of the `module` object.  If you assign something else to that property, then it replaces the prior object with whatever you assigned to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You replaced the `module.exports` object with a string so when you then log it, you just see the string as the object is gone.  So, this assignment:

```
module.exports ="Hello World";
```

takes the object that was in the `exports` property on the `module` object and replaces it with a string.  So, now when you log `module.exports`, you just see the string that you replaced it with.

Perhaps you meant to do something like:

```
module.exports.greeting = "Hello World";
```

where you leave the object in place and add a property to it.

This is all just plain Javascript so `exports` is just a property of the `module` object. If you assign something else to that property, then it replaces the prior object with whatever you assigned to it.

---

It's pretty much the same conceptually to this:

```js
let myexports = { name: "Hi I'm an object" };
console.log(myexports);

myexports = "Hi I'm a string";    // replace object with a string
console.log(myexports);
```

In either case, you're assigning a string into a variable/property and replacing the previous object with that string.

Answer (score 1):

Technically Module is an object as is visible in the log.

When you import it in another file it will provide the data you exported which is 'Hello World' string.

While the exported value can be a string, number, whatever, module.exports is still an object.

For a detailed explanation/understanding of module.exports and require read https://stackify.com/node-js-module-exports/